# Error occurred executing external native build for ndkBuild in android studio

Tags: android, icecast, ndk-build

I used [coolMic repo](https://github.com/CoolMicApp/CoolMicApp-Android)for broadcasting audio from android device.

But When i import it in android studio i got following error:-

```
E:\New folder (2)\CoolMicApp-Android\app\build.gradle
Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild E:\New folder (2)\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk
Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild E:\New folder (2)\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk
```

I checked on some resources but not help to resolve this.
Also From coolMic document where i follow the steps:-

```
How to build coolmic:
1. Download Android Studio and the NDK
2. Clone this repository
3. Run the following commands:
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
4. Import the Project into Android Studio. Select gradle-wrapper. 
5. Hit build(Arrovdown with 011001 next to it. 
6. Hit the Build Menu and then Build APK
7. You can find the resulting APK under ./app/build/outputs/apk/
```

Answer (score 12):

This error only occurs when your project path location having the folder name that contains white-space.

***For ex.***

> -> **Problem path** :- D:\**Android Project**\ProjectName\app\jni\android.mk
>
> In the problem path, folder name has with whitespace like "**Android
>   Project**"

=================================

> -> **Solution path** :- D:\**Android_Project**\ProjectName\app\jni\android.mk
>
> In the solution path, folder name does not have any whitespace like
>   "**Android_project**"

Comment: I don't even have any white spaces in the path and it still occur

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue for me! Was battling for over a day with this stupid thing :)

Comment: @prince thanks brother, Dealing with these NDK problem is really messy.. you saved my time

Comment: @ChiragJoshi It's my pleasure brother.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i resolved the issue.[image: Ndk build issue with android studio]
There is warning when you create new project in android studio with c or c++:-

```
Project location should not contain any white-space this cause problem with Ndk tools
```

I completely missed this.as my location E:\New folder(2)\New
so just change my path everything works fine